Mapping Attributes to Several Statuses with Date of Each Status in My Data Warehouse Fact Table
I hope you are well. I have this problem and I am a beginner in datawerehousing. I hope to find a solution to it.
I have an OLTP database from the GLPI system. We are only interested in ticket management (a ticket is an issue raised by an employee in the form of a ticket). Each ticket can have several statuses: new, in progress, pending, planned, resolved, closed. In the OLTP database (data source), each time the status of a ticket is modified, the 'status' attribute is also updated, along with the modification date. Additionally, we have ticket closing and resolution dates.
Our job is to create a dashboard to track and visualize the number of tickets for each period, as well as the statuses of each ticket during each period.
The ETL runs every day. Our problem is how to capture these ticket transactions and display them. The supervisor suggested the idea of creating a fact table for each status, but we found that this is not logical. and how I can keep the history and display the statuses of each ticket by date for example the month passed how many tickets were closed
How can I solve this problem?

You need to design "Accumulating Snapshot" fact table: https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/accumulating-snapshot-fact-table/

If you make the dimension table that holds the status an SCD2 table then you'll have the history.
If you don't want/need to create a fact table to report on this, you can just query the SCD2 Dimension table to get the information you want.
